# Trouble handling nested JSON data

Tags: javascript, json, parsing, syntax

I have a JSON data and i'm having trouble with one nested object. You can see there is two metadata object, my aim is to get image link.

```
obj.metadata.url
```

is working, but this isn't work.

```
obj.metadata.metadata.image
```

what am i missing here?

```json
{
  "tokenId": "0",
  "metadata": {
    "url": "https://gateway.pinata.cloud/ipfs/QmSnTNGbhD/0",
    "metadata": {
      "name": "Illuminati #0",
      "image": "https://gateway.pinata.cloud/ipfs/QmW8pAhkNr/5499.png",
      "attributes": [
        {
          "trait_type": "Background",
          "value": "Stained Glass"
        },
        {
          "trait_type": "Frames",
          "value": "Stained Glass"
        }
      ]
    },
    "tokenId": "0"
  }
}
```

Comment: Your code works, so `obj` is not just the JSON response / is something else entirely.

Comment: but there is no problem when try; obj.metadata.url

Comment: Your object could simply be `{ metadata: { url: 'https://....' } }` without the nested metdata object. In that case `obj.metadata.url` would work, but `obj.metadata.metadata.image` would not work. Try doing `console.log(obj)` to ensure your data is what you expect.

Answer (score -1):

From your question it seems that you are dealing with JSON data instead of JavaScript objects. In order to get the attributes of JSON, you will first need to parse the `JSON` using `JSON.parse()`, then you can use `.` to get the properties you want.

```
data = {
  "tokenId": "0",
  "metadata": {
     "url": "https://gateway.pinata.cloud/ipfs/QmSnTNGbhD/0",
      "metadata": {
      "name": "Illuminati #0",
      "image": "https://gateway.pinata.cloud/ipfs/QmW8pAhkNr/5499.png",
      "attributes": [
      {
        "trait_type": "Background",
        "value": "Stained Glass"
      },
      {
        "trait_type": "Frames",
        "value": "Stained Glass"
      }
     ]
  },
  "tokenId": "0"
  }
};

obj = JSON.parse(data);
console.log(obj.metadata.url)
// 'https://gateway.pinata.cloud/ipfs/QmSnTNGbhD/0'
console.log(obj.metadata.metadata.image);
// 'https://gateway.pinata.cloud/ipfs/QmW8pAhkNr/5499.png'
```

Comment: `obj.metadata.url` would not work if `obj` was a JSON string.

Comment: Absolutely yes, he first needs to convert in JavaScript object.

Comment: But he's saying `obj.metadata.url` already does work, indicating that `obj` is not a string.

Comment: Understand @xdumaine that makes sense, thanks. I totally misunderstand the question. But technically JSON must be parse before it can be used. What do you think?